# How can I update cached data when server data is updated in firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to reduce reads on documents in firestore using cache stored data instead of requesting it from server. Docs are rarely be updated or added.

How I am currently fetching data:

```
const querySnapshot = await getDocsFromCache(q);
        if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
          console.log("From cache");
          const docs = querySnapshot.docs;
          return docs;
        } else {
          const snapshot = await getDocs(q);
          const docs = snapshot.docs;
          console.log("From server");
          return docs;
        }
```

Using getDocsFromCache(), if there isn't stored data in cache then I would use getDocs().
When data is updated in server, cache isn't updated so I don't get the updated data.
I would like to know how to listen to changes on my firestore db without having to read using getDocs().
If not possible, I'm wondering if I can expire cache daily so users have to request data from server at least once daily.

Thanks!

Comment: I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-drastically-reduce-the-number-of-reads-when-no-documents-are-changed-in-firestore-8760e2f25e9e) will help.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know how to listen to changes on my firestore db without having to read using getDocs().

This isn't possible.  The only way to know if there is anything new is to actually read the documents, and that will always incur the cost of reads.

> If not possible, I'm wondering if I can expire cache daily so users have to request data from server at least once daily.

You can't select which documents to expire from the cache.  The cache is maintained by the SDK and it always decides which documents stay in the cache and which are evicted.  The main purpose of the cache is actually for times when your app is temporarily offline, and it's not for long-term use, so think carefully before depending on it.

If you want control over your cache, you should implement your own caching system. It's much harder than it sounds.

Comment: Thank you! I think I got mislead by [this](https://youtu.be/iQOTjUko9WM?t=402) video. They talk about caching as a reliable way to serve data without incurring in billed reads, if the database doesn't change too much.

Comment: Maybe it's reliable if your database is read-only and small enough to fit entirely in cache without the risk of evictions. But that really isn't the designed use case.